# python tools on visualstudio doesn't debug exceptions

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, ironpython

I'm running VS pro 2015 with Python Tools. When I run Python code which has to throw an exception I got only a flashing and unreadable exception in the program window. For example I expect that this code:

```
  a = 1 + "hello"
```

move the focus from the console window to Visual Studio, but it doesnt (debug is simply stopped).

Python Exceptions are flagged in the Exceptions Settings panel, by the way. How can I fix?